# Live Messenger app Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, instant-messaging

I want to create an Instant Messaging app for Windows Phone.
I have found some information about Live SDK, but it looks like the messenger api is outdated?

Can anyone help me start? All I want to do at first is embed the IM. 
A simple IM app where the user logs in with their Live ID, sees who already has the app (Live Contacts) and an IM-service with a UI like the SMS-service in windows phone.

Can anyone help me get started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly i hope i got your question right.
I have multiple lookouts for you:

XMPP (Jabber): start from there. It is fairly simple, and there are opensource clients out there where you can dismantle code and learn by understanding what others have done.

Check out the SignalR
ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes it incredibly simple to add real-time web functionality to your applications. It's the ability to have your server-side code push content to the connected clients as it happens, in real-time.
You may have heard of WebSockets, a new HTML5 API that enables bi-directional communication between the browser and server. SignalR will use WebSockets under the covers when it's available, and gracefully fallback to other techniques and technologies when it isn't, while your application code stays the same.
SignalR also provides a very simple, high-level API for doing server to client RPC (call JavaScript functions in your clients' browsers from server-side .NET code) in your ASP.NET application, as well as adding useful hooks for connection management, e.g. connect/disconnect events, grouping connections, authorization.

Comment: I'm thinking more like embedding Skype IM inside my app. Is there an api for that?

Comment: As far as i have seen and done, unless you have any sdk which provides support for such things, there is no way you can have embedding of some app in yours.

Generally, Wp8 uses tasks for launching apps and similar pages which can be added in the flow of your app. But i have not yet seen any embedded kind of IM in wp8 as of now.

Comment: Facebook has its sdk for wp8 integration but apparently even that does not provide support for IM integration. Not even skype i suppose. Launching other apps is what works in wp8.. not embedding..
Else creating a new Im from scratch using the two ways which i stated.
Hope this helps. Do vote up or accept as answer if it guided you in the right direction.
Thanks and Cheers.